# Issue with Joining multiple tables in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have three Entities that are linked together using annotations. I have a `User`, `Student` and `Recording` table.

Currently the Recording Entity contains a StudentID field which is linked to a Student Entity, and the Student Entity's ID is linked to a UserID in the User entity.

My problem is that when I get an array of Recording objects via a query using Doctrine:

```
$studentRecordings = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('StudentBundle:Recording')
            ->findBy(
            array('pageID' => $pageObject, 'studentID' => $studentObject),
            array('filename' => 'ASC')
        );
```

I get an error unable to access the student information.

```
["studentID"]=>
  object(stdClass)#552 (6) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(39) "Acme\studentBundle\Entity\Student"
    ["__IS_PROXY__"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["__PROXY_INITIALIZED__"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["id"]=>
    NULL
    ["class"]=>
    NULL
    ["parent"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

This then give's me an error `Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in StudentBundle/Entity/Student.php`

Recording.php:

```
class Recording
{

    public $file;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $recordingID;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pageID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $pageID;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Student")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="student", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $studentID;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="filename", type="string")
     */
    protected $filename;
```

Student.php

```
class Student
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Classes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="class", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $class;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $parent;
```

User.php

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $first_name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $last_name;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Role")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $role;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $username;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $password;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $email;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="integer")
     */
    protected $isActive;
```

EDIT: Okay so basically the Student Object has a getID function that basically returns `$this->student->getID();`
the error is that `$this->student` should be an object and it doesnt seem to be in this scenario.

EDIT 2: Okay I've come a cross a very weird situation.  Let's say I have two student accounts with ID 1 and 5, When I call the `getRepository()` as student 1, if I specify that `'studentID' => 1`, it gives that error, if however, I change it to `'student' => 5` it works.  This happens as well when I'm logged into student 5 and do the same thing.

Basically it only gives the the error if it matches the Logged in Student

Comment: Can you show the full error text from 'unable to access the student information'? Or is that the error text you provided? Also, where is the `getId` method defined? Lastly, I can only assume the line number of your errors match up to the `getDoctrine` call?

Comment: I added where the getID was coming from at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't use `StudentID =1` . You need to have the Student Object.
StudentID is your Student Object.

you Naming is wrong. In your class it should be like

protected `$student` not `$studentID`

Then in the query you need to have the Student Object like this

`$student = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('StudentBundle:Student').find(1)`

`array('pageID' => $pageObject, 'student' => $student)`

Comment: The name was studentID before it had any relational mapping, and because it was called in many other locations, I decided to not change it, nevertheless that would not cause any issues as $studentID is still an object not an integer. also, sorry that integer was a test, it does work. but the original was a $student Object

Comment: Before trying anything in the controller, try executing the query in sql in phpmyadmin , so that you can debug where is the problem. If you sql is returning results usually 95% of time controller also works

Answer (score 0):

Typo in the name of the join Column?

```
class Recording
{
//..

  /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Student")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="student_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $studentID;
}
```

Comment: how so? the name `id` generates a table `Recording` with a column called `id`

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Student")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="student_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
  protected $studentID;
```

to

```
/**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Student")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="studentID_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
  protected $studentID;
```

if you keep var name also need to keep it in joincolumn